# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, linq-to-entities

I'm getting this error when trying to add an "Entity" to site.

"An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

The Relation Between Site and "Entity" is one to many.

My Models Looks as below:

Site:

```
public class Site : Model
{
 // The collection of Entities belonging to this site
 public virtual ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

Entity:

```
public class Entity : Model
{
 public string Label { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
}
```

My Code in Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(EntityModel _entityModel)
{
  var model = _entityModel.ToEntity();
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    model.Site = _siteRepository.Find(1);
    model.Label = model.Name.Replace(' ','_').ToLower();
    _entityRepository.Add(model);
  }

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Code in EFEntityRepository.cs:

```
public void Add(Entity entity)
{
  DateTime dateModified = DateTime.Now;
  entity.CreatedOn = dateModified;
  entity.LastUpdatedOn = dateModified;
  this._context.Entities.Add(entity);
  this._context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Do you use two different `_context` instances in `_siteRepository` and in `_entityRepository`? This would be the reason for the exception.

Comment: What does `_entityModel.ToEntity()` do?

Comment: Hi you can find complete source code document in the path https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lYThMsXGnd2UoG-BdBiwRYDyo2Db3reF3osSDfOipO0/edit

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like somewhere you have multiple Context classes holding a reference to this object, possibly by key.
Ensure your context is disposed after every request and in addition, there is no other operation causing another context instance to hold onto this entity.

Comment: I'm New to Entity Framework, In the above "EFEntityRepository.cs" where i has to call the dispose method. please help

Comment: Need more code ... I don't see where you create your context or repository

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your reply. You can find complete source code document in the location https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lYThMsXGnd2UoG-BdBiwRYDyo2Db3reF3osSDfOipO0/edit?pli=1

Comment: You aren't disposing your original context when done with the request.  You will need to tell Ninject to dispose of your repositories after _every request_ and in turn in your repository implement IDisposable to dispose of the context after _every request_  I dont use Ninject, so can't give you the particular syntax here.